# Mootools - set style for dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mootools

I have an asp net application where I use dropdown list. It is not a standard one. In order to display this I use mootools, so I use scrollbar and dropdownList Container. 
Now I need to able to change style (display value from block into none) of my dropdown list within the code behind.

When I do it in a normal way `dList.Style.Add("display", "none")` nothing has changed.

How might I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what “normal way” you are referring to, but you should take a look at [MooTools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/). The method you're looking for is, quite unsurprisingly, in the [`Element.Style`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Style#Element%3asetStyle) part.

```
dList.setStyle('display', 'none');
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The problem is that the dropdownlist control is override in mootools and this one from mootools only get value from dropdownlist. But I solved the problem by changing display mode for mootools' elements

Comment: Because in general it is a good answer, but in this case it didn't help.

Comment: @ravenik Then if it did not solve your problem, please describe precisely what solved it as an answer, and accept yours! It is more important that future users know what to do  :)  I didn't get what you meant by “changing display mode for MooTools' elements”.